# Как можно эффективно найти опечатки в словах?

Tags: c#, .net

Задача: Есть предложения и нужно получить список похожих слов.

Пробовал вот такой путь, но он не эффективен:

Я удаляю всю пунктуацию и делю все на слова, деля по пробелу.

В итоге у меня получается ~170 000 уникальных слов.

Далее, я думал все это прогнать через какой-нибудь алгоритм вычисления похожести слов, например Расстояние Левенштейна, а потом используя некоторых критерий похожести получить похожие отсея слова, которые очень сильно отличаются для ручного просмотра и корректировки.

Однако, сравнивая слова между собой-это где-то 170 000^2 итераций => долго.

Как можно повысить эффективность?

Comment: приведите слово в lowercase, там останутся только буквы (латинские?) в нижнем регистре. Создайте массив из 26 (для латиницы) элементов для каждого слова, храните в этом массиве счетчики количества каждой буквы в слове. Сравнением 2 слов станет сравнение 2 массивов по 26 элементов, Левенштейна применяйте если, например, счетчики букв отличаются на 2, например - это ументшит стоимость одного сравнения

Comment: Чтобы уменьшить количество сравнений, я бы отсортировал строки чем то типа [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885936/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5/886029#886029) - сортировка выполняется линейно

Comment: предполагая, что похожие слова начинаются одинаково, то в отсортированном массиве они должны быть рядом. Хотя я могу быть и не прав - зависит от того, что вы понимаете под похожими словами

Comment: Можно ещё придумать что то, но оно будет зависеть от специфики языка

Comment: Попробую исключить сравнение слишком длинных с короткими. А так же на основании частоты встречаемости предполагать, что тот или иной случай не ошибочный. Ещё попробую как вы сказали сравнивать только те, что начинаются на одну букву так как вероятность ошибки крайне мала. По идее, таким образом сравниваемая выборка будет меньше.

Comment: удачи :) (7 символов)

Comment: @tym32167, как-то не особо помогло. Как я понимаю, завтык может быть в том, что у меня получается огроменный HashSet в который со временм тяжело вставлять https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891559/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: Не очень понял, причем тут хешсет? У вас изначально ест массив строк из 170000 элементов. Вы его сортируете — линейная операция (используя сортировку, что я вам указал). Получаете сортированный массив строк. Потом потом строите второй массив - со счетчиками букв - для помощи в сравнении. Потом берете строку с индексом 0 и сравниваете со следующими 100 строками. Если строка строка с индексом i похожа на строку с индексом j, то в результат пишем эти два числа.можете завести словарь, который индекс слова как ключ и набор индексов похожих слов как значение. В итоге в словаре не больше 170т ключей.

Comment: То есть делаете словарь `Dictionary<int, hashset<int>> result`, и если слово с индексом i похоже на слово с индексом j, то `result[i].Add(j); result[j].Add(i);` - у вас же граф слов, а это типичное представление графа.

Comment: Если вы хотите хранить информацию о том, насколько одно слово похоже на другое (то есть градации похожести), то значит у вас граф взвешенный, вам надо будет написать класс ребра с 2 полями - степень похожести и индекс второго слова, и вместо хешсета индексов в результате в качестве значения словаря хранить список ребер похожих слов