# Работа с большой коллекцией

Tags: c#, .net

В общем есть вот такой класс:

```
 class Metric
    {
        public Word Word1;
        public Word Word2;

        public Metric(Word word1, Word word2)
        {
            Word1 = word1;
            Word2 = word2;
        }
        public int Simil;
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Word1.GetHashCode() + Word2.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

public class Word
{
    public string Text;

    public Word(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Text.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Класс содержит в себе данные о похожести 2-ух слов.

Есть класс, который содержит в себе поле с типом HashSet.

Так вот, когда коллекция достигает размера в несколько миллионов, то становится заметно, что процесс не так шустро, как в самом начале добавления.

Можно ли как-нибудь избежать этого? По идее, LinkedList будет шустрым, но тогда я лишаюсь проверки на уникальность проверяемых пар слов, а это я использую, что бы не пересчитывать одно и тоже повторно.

Answer (score 0):

Кэшируйте результат `GetHashCode`:

```
class Metric
{
    private int fHashCode;
    public Word Word1 { get; private set; }
    public Word Word2 { get; private set; }

    public Metric(Word word1, Word word2)
    {
        Word1 = word1;
        Word2 = word2;

       fHashCode = Word1.GetHashCode() + Word2.GetHashCode();
    }
    public int Simil;
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return fHashCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм... А мне казалось, что при добавлении элемента в HashSet он сам вычисляет хеш и запоминает его, что бы потом не пересчитывать для всех элементов при добавлении. Тем не менее, хоть процесс и пошел шустрее, но пробуксовка началась несколько позже теперь=(

Comment: @iluxa1810 может дело в алгоритме вычисления хэшкода и количестве коллизий?

Comment: Алгоритм вычисления можно сказать, чтотисполтзуется стандартная для строк с той лишь разницей, что плюсуются хеш-коды двух строк. Мы же не переопределяем хеш-код для базовых типов => это должно работать. Коллизии не понижали бы производительность так как элемент просто не добавлялись.

Comment: *Коллизии не понижали бы производительность так как элемент просто не добавлялись.* — с чего вы взяли? https://ideone.com/XiIyKd