# Сортировка списка объектов с полями типа string по одному из параметров,которое на самом деле -целое число C#

Tags: c#

Есть список объектов,в нём множество полей типа string(хотя на самом деле под стрингом скрываются и целочисленные значения) .Проблема в том,что я не понимаю,как можно отсортировать этот список по тому целочисленному полю.
Вот,что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
public class TopLevelItemComparer : IComparer<Theater>
{
    public int Compare(Theater x, Theater y)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(x.MainHall).CompareTo(
               Int32.Parse(y.MainHall));
    }
}
 currentList.Sort(new TopLevelItemComparer());
```

И вылетает исключение System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."
Как можно пофиксить,чтобы это не занимало кучу строк?

PS 
Изменил код вот так:

```
public int Compare(Theater x, Theater y)
{
    if (x.MainHall == null) x.MainHall = "0";
    if (y.MainHall == null) y.MainHall = "0";
    return Double.Parse(x.MainHall).CompareTo(
           Double.Parse(y.MainHall));
}
```

Но он всё равно падает.
PSS Решение нашёл:

```
public int Compare(Theater x, Theater y)
{
    string x11 = x.MainHall;
    string y11 = y.MainHall;
    if (x.MainHall == "") x.MainHall = "0";
    if (y.MainHall == "") y.MainHall = "0";
    int k = Double.Parse(x.MainHall).CompareTo(
           Double.Parse(y.MainHall));
    x.MainHall = x11;
    y.MainHall = y11;
    return k;
}
```

Перед сравнение надо запомнить начальные значения поля MainHall,затем проверить на пустоту именно сравнение с "" ,а не с null. После сравнения задать поля обратно.

Comment: у вас свойство `MainHall` не всегда содержит число, потому и падает ваш код

Comment: Да,иногда пустая строка

Comment: Я бы вставил в try { Int32.Parse(x.MainHall)} catch() и лишь после этого делал compare. Совершенно не факт, что строках у Вас нет еще  еще что-нибудь кроме целых

Comment: целые числа и пустота,да(MainHall означает вместимость в главном зале театра,но если там пустота,это ещё не факт ,что вместимость 0,значит заменять на 0 нельзя)

Comment: Кстати, если речь идет о местах в зале, то все они положительные, и мне кажется в этом случае можно обойтись, встроенным compare для строк :)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов для таких целей есть `TryParse`

Comment: нет,он сортирует некорректно : сначала идут пустые строки,потом строки,которые начинаются с единицы,потом с двойки и так далее.Но проблему я решил,Спасибо

Comment: И как вы учитываете пустоту в вашем коде? Пустота никак не спарсится в число, как вы сортировать собрались с учетом пустоты?

Comment: @tym32167 - это уже мелкие детали. Важно, чтобы была предусмотрена обработка исключений, Вы не находите.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов есть большая разница в производительности между `try/catch` и `TryParse`. Обработка исключений это хорошо в меру, но не надо в каждую дырку `try/catch` пихать, так можно и по производительности просесть, и как вы эту ошибку логгировать собрались? В данном случае `try/catch` будет действительно лишней конструкцией.

Comment: @tym32167 Мне важно было сейчас сам код написать,я чего-то долго с этим промучался,обработка исключений здесь не так важна,потому что гарантируется наличие только чисел или пустоты.

Comment: @TheGreatNeo-NEO- я писал комментарий не вам, а другому человеку. Вам уже дали оч хороший ответ ниже :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо определиться, как сортировать строки, если там не числа.

Предположим, если одна из строк не является числом, то мы сравниваем эти строки, как строки.

```
public int Compare(Theater x, Theater y)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(x.MainHall, out int mainHall1)
     && Int32.TryParse(y.MainHall, out int maihHall2)
         return mainHall1.CompareTo(mainHall2);

    return string.Compare(x.MainHall, y.MainHall);
}
```

Comment: ответ плюсанул, он абсолютно тут уместен, просто оставлю сылку на [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/886029/179763) для тех случаев, если кому то нужно будет сортировать быстро большой объем строк с цифрами

Comment: Спасибо,это вообще супер

Answer (score 0):

я думаю все слишком усложнено.

Для чего вообще писать свой компаратор обьекта если можно воспользоватся готовым компаратором, собственно, твоего инта или стринга?

---

Предсавим себе список обьектов:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string AgeStr => Age.ToString();
}
```

и у нас есть список инстансов:

```
List<Person> users; //представим что он уже заполнен
```

теперь давай его отсортируем по Age:

```
var sortedUsers = users.Order(x => Int32.Parse(x.AgeStr)).ToList();

var sortedUsersDesc = users.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.AgeStr) ).ToList();
```

если нужно отсортировать по другому параметру просто замени AgeStr на нужное название другого параметра.

Comment: Проблема в том ,что в переменной типа string хранится целое число,и отстортировать надо именно по убыванию чисел,через лямбда так сделать не получается

Comment: и почему не получится отсортировать по убыванию? OrderByDescending именно для этого и придумали

Comment: Вы не поняли,там string k="1234", к примеру

Comment: В таком случае никто не запрещает сделать `var sortedUsersDesc = users.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.AgeStr) ).ToList();`