# O-большое для sort() / sorted() в Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

Во время изучения стандартных функций и методов Python, возник вопрос по поводу реализации `sort()` и `sorted()` в Python. Насколько быстро они работают и есть ли вообще смысл писать алгоритм, например, быстрой сортировки, решая олимпиадные задачи, или сэкономить время, просто написав `myArr.sort()`?

Comment: Как вы думаете, вы напишете лучше и быстрее, чем написано профессиональными программистами? Если вы считаете, что Python разработан полными кретинами - почему вы им вообще пользуетесь? Просто интереса ради - напишите свой вариант и сравните по времени с питоновским. Будет интересно посмотреть...

Comment: @Harry: дело не в "кретинизме" создателей, а в том, что большая часть нативной библиотеки Python реализована на ~~нормальном языке~~ C++. Так что неважно, насколько оптимальные там использовались алгоритмы: интерпретируемому Python'y в любом случае в жизни не догнать по времени работы скомпилированную сборку

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Идеально написанный алгоритм сортировки O(N^2) все равно проиграет плохо написанному O(N log N). Главная оптимизация всегда в применяемом алгоритме, а не в вылизывании ассемблерных команд :)

Comment: @Harry: если же рассматривать вопрос ТС в вакууме, не привязывая его к питону, где все очевидно, то не надо считать разработчиков языка богами, которые никогда не совершают ошибок. Все мы люди, все мы иногда где-то косячим. Так что в редких случаях все же можно найти разделы стандартной библиотеки языка, которые работают не так быстро, как могли бы)

Comment: @Harry: а вот с питоном - не факт, не факт. Я весьма и весьма допускаю, что "идеально написанный алгоритм сортировки O(N^2)" на С++ (в условном ядре библиотеки) с треском проиграет "плохо написанному O(NlogN)" на питоне

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Я не знаю Python, так что моя реализация сортировки O(N log N) будет весьма корявой. Давайте сравним ее по времени с вашей сортировкой O(N^2), написанной на С/С++/ассемблере. Устраивает такой способ разрешения вопроса?

Comment: @Harry: таки можно попробовать :D

Comment: @Harry точно, и запустить её на 10 элементах :) Хотя, мне кжется, и на 1000 чисел С++ будет выигрывать тупо из за более быстрого старта приложения. Вот на 10 миллионов или 10 миллиардов это уже да, асимптотика вывезет.

Comment: @tym32167: поддерживаю) Будет действительно интересно проверить)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Ну, тогда мне нужно время на изучение, как работать в Питоне с массивами и т.д. На сегодня мои знания ограничены простейшими арифметическими действиями... Когда что-то напишу - будем посмотреть. И, понятно, что на небольших массивах питон будет побит, это очевидно.

Comment: @Harry как и очевидно, что на очень большом массиве данных асимптотика вывезет, что тогда тут проверять/доказывать? )

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Подождите, а как же ваше *большая часть нативной библиотеки Python реализована на ~~нормальном языке~~ C++. Так что **неважно, насколько оптимальные там использовались алгоритмы**: интерпретируемому Python'y в любом случае в жизни не догнать по времени работы скомпилированную сборку* - я воспринимаю это как "неважно, насколько хороший алгоритм будет взят на Python - на C++ его обставит любой другой - просто за счет компилируемости". В то время как я утверждал, что выбор алгоритма важнее компилируемости, и не пытался утверждать, что один и тот же код будет быстрее в Python.

Comment: @Harry: да, Вы понимаете правильно) Конечно, асимптотика рано или поздно возьмёт своё (и мне как раз интересно, когда наступит это самое "рано или поздно"), но, видится мне, что на массивах среднестатистического размера даже откровенно плохая реализация какого-либо алгоритма сортировки на языке компилируемом выиграет у на порядок более лучшей на питоне

Answer (score 3):

Стандартные алгоритмы из фреймворков предназначены для решения большого круга задач, то есть это алгоритмы общего назначения, которые вам помогут в общем случае и они скорее всего работают за O(NLogN). Во время решения олимпиадных задач вы будете [знать контекст применения алгорима](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/886029/179763) и в некоторых случаях вы сможете применить более оптимальную сортировку (например, сортировку подсчетом или, поразрядные сортировки), которая может быть быстрее стандартной. Потому если вы видите возможность отсортировать ваши данные быстрее, чем за O(NlogN), то пишите свою сортировку, если нет, то не надо изобретать быструю сортировку или сортировку слиянием - используйте стандартную.

Answer (score 3):

В ответ на то, что важнее - алгоритм или компилируемость...

Вот, как смог, так и наваял на Python - надеюсь, достаточно коряво? :)

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def qsort(M, b, e):
   if b == e:
      return;
   l = b;
   r = e;
   pivot = M[l];
   while l <= r:
       while M[l] < pivot:
           l = l + 1;
       while M[r] > pivot:
           r = r - 1;
       if l <= r:
           t = M[l];
           M[l] = M[r];
           M[r] = t;
           l = l+1;
           r = r - 1;


   if b < r:
        qsort(M,b,r);

   if e > l:
        qsort(M,l,e);
   return;

Idx = 100000

M = np.random.randint(0, Idx, Idx)

start = timer()
qsort(M,0,Idx-1);
end = timer()

print(end - start)

#for i in range(0,Idx):
#    print(M[i]);
```

А вот - вставки на C++:

```
void insertionSort(vector<int>& data)
{
    vector<int>::iterator b = data.begin(), e = data.end(), i, j, k;
    i = b;
    for(++i; i != e; ++i)
    {
        j = k = i;
        for(--j; (k != b) && (*k < *j); --j, --k)
        {
            swap(*k,*j);
        }
    }
}
```

Результаты на моей машине (примерно, по нескольким запускам, в ms; измерение **только** сортировки)

```
Размер         Quick_Python    Insertion_Cpp

    1000              4              0,4
   10000             51             38
  100000            635           4010
 1000000           7500       не дождался
```

Выводы делайте сами :)

Comment: Не удержались и написали сразу обе версии? :D Собственно, как я и полагал: на среднестатистических размерностях фактор компилируемости возобладает над асимптотикой)

Answer (score 1):

Экспериментальным путем делал так - создавал рандомный массив из n элементов, 
0 < myArr[i] < n.
Путём несложных операций получились вот такие результаты, время на создание массивов не учитывалось:

```
sort():
    10.000 = 0.004 (то есть массив из 10.000 эл., каждый эл. равен {1, 10.000})
    100.000 = 0.015
    1.000.000 = 0.228
    10.000.000 = 3.445

sorted():
    10.000 = 0.004
    100.000 = 0.015
    1.000.000 = 0.232
    10.000.000 = 3.476

algorithm:
    10.000 = 0.020
    100.000 = 0.311
    1.000.000 = 4.286
    10.000.000 = 62.884
```

Алгоритм для сравнения с встроенными функциями использовался вот такой (алгоритм быстрой сортировки):

```
def quicksort(array):
  if len(array) < 2:
    # base case, arrays with 0 or 1 element are already "sorted"
    return array
  else:
    # recursive case
    pivot = array[0]
    # sub-array of all the elements less than the pivot
    less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot]
    # sub-array of all the elements greater than the pivot
    greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]
    return quicksort(less) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)
```

Конечно, эксперимент неидеален, каждый раз создавался новый массив, этим я пренебрёг. Для многих, если не для всех, очевидно, что стандартные функции и методы работают намного быстрее, но тем не менее, как минимум теперь есть конкретные значения и разница на лицо.

Comment: Получаем, что Си на низкоуровневых операциях как минимум в 18 раз быстрее питона, что со всей очевидностью определяет области применения. Т.е., все же, питон это типичный скриптовый язык.

Comment: @avp откуда такие выводы? Взяли какой то код на С++ и абсолютно другой код на питоне, запустили на каких то рандомных данных - как на этом вообще какие либо выводы можно строить? И что тут доказали? Что интерпретатор работает не за бесплатно?

Comment: @tym32167, какой-то код на Си (если не ошибаюсь потроха питона это именно Си, а не кресты) это реализация его сортировки (и он работает быстро, гугл утверждает, что это stable sort (видимо какая-то из разновидностей merge sort)). Питоновская реализация автора, как видим, это наивный quicksort. В принципе, quicksort д.б алгоритмически . быстрее (но то же `O(N * log N)). Поэтому мы и можем сравнивать, т.е. оценивать качество реализации интерпретатора

Comment: @avp я думаю, это в принципе неверно, сравнивать интерпретатор с сями, и тем более неверно сравнивать разные алгоритмы, и ещё более не верно делать на этом выводы, так как бог его знает, какие ещё доп оптимизации можно было бы сделать на си и на питоне, но не смотря на это, по моему очевидно, что если бы был бы абсолютно идентичный код на питоне и на си, то интерпретатор бы добавил времени работы питону, на то си и низкоуровневый.

Comment: @tym32167, обе реализации решают одну и ту же задачу -- сортируют набор данных, поэтому сравнение корректно (imho). Выводы же, что именно  имеет смысл использовать для решения конкретной задачи, каждый может сделать сам.

Comment: @avp `обе реализации решают одну и ту же задачу -- сортируют набор данных, поэтому сравнение корректно (imho)` не могу с этим согласиться, но мы походу одно и то же перемалываем в беседе :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98935/discussion-between-avp-and-tym32167).